# ErrorProvider dinamico

Tags: c#

Buenos días tengo una función que recorre las cajas de texto de un formulario y me devuelve una lista con el nombre de las cajas que están vacías.
La intención es tratarlas después con un `foreach` y pasarle al `errorProvider` el control mediante el `string` de la lista. 
Pero el `ErrorProvider` quiere el control, no el nombre. Como puedo decirle al `ErrorProvider` esto:

```
formError.SetError(*control.Name=lista[0]*,"campo requerido");
```

Espero haberme explicado, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

En vez de `control.Name=lista[0]` puedes buscar el objeto mediante el método `Find` de la colección `Controls` y hacer referencia a él.

```
Form1.Controls.Find(lista[0])
```